# How can I group my radio buttons visually?

Tags: html, material-design

Hi i'm trying to make a form and i'm blocked because i don't know how to make radio button groups

Here is my code:

```html
<!-- Pose des poteaux -->

<!-- 1st group -->
<div>
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-1">
    <input type="radio" id="option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1" checked>
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur dalle - Pose à la française</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-2">
    <input type="radio" id="option-2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre dalle - Pose à l'anglaise</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-3">
    <input type="radio" id="option-3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="3" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur acrotère - pose à la Française</span>
  </label>
</div>

<!-- 2nd group -->
  <br>
  <div>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-4">
    <input type="radio" id="option-4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="4" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre acrotère - Pose à l'anglaise extérieure</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-5">
    <input type="radio" id="option-5" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="5" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre acrotère - Pose à l'anglaise intérieure</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

It's supposed to have 2 groups of radio buttons but still not working.

Comment: What part of your code makes you say "it supposed to have 2 groups?"

Comment: I assume that you mean visually and not with respect to the form submission. If that's wrong, please edit the title (but don't tack on tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give a different name to the buttons in group 2

```html
<!-- Pose des poteaux -->

<!-- 1st group -->
<div>
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-1">
    <input type="radio" id="option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1" checked>
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur dalle - Pose à la française</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-2">
    <input type="radio" id="option-2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre dalle - Pose à l'anglaise</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-3">
    <input type="radio" id="option-3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="3" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur acrotère - pose à la Française</span>
  </label>
</div>

<!-- 2nd group -->
  <br>
  <div>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-4">
    <input type="radio" id="option-4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options2" value="4" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre acrotère - Pose à l'anglaise extérieure</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-5">
    <input type="radio" id="option-5" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options2" value="5" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre acrotère - Pose à l'anglaise intérieure</span>
  </label>
</div>
```